# angularjs routeProvider not working on live server

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have just uploaded a project to a live server from my localhost, but I'm having a bit trouble with some links!
In my routeProvider I have this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/projects/:project', {
  templateUrl: 'partials/projectPage.html',
  controller: 'ProjectPageCtrl'
})
```

But when I go to page that are in a link text mysite. com/projects/testing, the hole site crashes and I get this error in the console:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
at eval (native)
at mysite. com/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2:14066
at Function.p.extend.globalEval (mysite. com/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2:14077)
at p.ajaxSetup.converters.text script (mysite. com/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2:83767)
at cC (mysite. com/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2:5858)
at y (mysite. com/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2:79924)
at d (mysite. com/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2:85578)
at Object.send (http://mysite. com/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2:85705)
at Function.p.extend.ajax (mysite. com/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2:82575)
at HTMLScriptElement.<anonymous> (mysite. com/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2:68258) <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope"> angular.js:9503
```

But when I'm running it on my localhost everything is working fine. So I have no idea what's wrong :(

Hope that someone can help me with this :)

Comment: Looks like the request for your templates are failing. You need to examine the request and see what's wrong with it. You can do this with the developer console, just google "inspect request google chrome console".

Comment: Okej I have found out the problem, first so was my base href wrong!
And for the second one so I switch to jQuery 1.7.2 and now it's working just fine, So it's seams to be a bug in jQuery 1.8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like backend error. If you're using REST API, make sure your JSON is valid. Similar errors are caused if you try to `JSON.parse` a HTML page:

[image]

Open the REST API url with your browser and see what's wrong. You can use the network tab to preview the response like this(assuming you're using Chrome, but most of the modern browsers can do this):

[image]

Comment: Well that's the problem, the controller that are gonna start men you go to page, never starts. But everything else work just fine, it is just when I to mysite. com/projects/somePage

Answer (score 0):

Okej I have found out the problem, first so was my base href wrong! And for the second one so I switch to jQuery 1.7.2 and now it's working just fine, So it's seams to be a bug in jQuery 1.8.0